# Why on my site i have too many redirects?

Tags: .htaccess

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.eccoci.online.it [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://eccoci.online/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} !^eccoci.online [nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} !^bigliettino.it [nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^bigliettino.it [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://bigliettino.it/network-nuovo [r=301,L]
```

error: too many redirects

Comment: You need to fix the code formatting (and don't use backslash-escapes in an attempt to format code). And check the code before submitting (I'm sure that `your text` bit is not in your code?!) Either indent by 4 spaces (you can use the button on the editor toolbar) or surround the code block or use "backtick fencing" (3 backticks). Use single backticks to format inline code - all instructions are in the editor.

Comment: You need to state what URL(s) you are requesting that cause the problem? What is the nature of the redirect loop, ie. what URL(s) are you being repeatedly redirected from/to? When did this redirect loop start happening? What did you change? How is SSL implemented on your server? Are you behind a front-end proxy that manages your SSL? If not then that could be the cause of your problem. However, you do realise you are redirecting to HTTPS in the first rule and HTTP in the second two?!

Comment: And (ignoring the "`your text`" anomaly) the two conditions that check `!^bigliettino.it` AND `^bigliettino.it` make no sense - both can't be true, so the rule does nothing. You need to take a step back and identify (describe in natural language) what you are trying to do here and what these directive actually mean.